# Is there a way to autopopulate MailingLatitude/MailingLongitude?

Tags: custom-field

My organization wants a report of all contacts living within 30 miles of our headquarters. I've created a custom field that uses the DISTANCE and GEOLOCATION functions to calculate the distance from our location to MAILINGLATITUDE/MAILINGLONGITUDE, but those fields are unpopulated. Is there a way to quickly autopopulate those fields?

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy way to do this, assuming you're using either the Account, Contact, or Lead.

Here are the release notes: [Summer 16 Release Notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer16/release-notes/rn_general_geocodes_aloha.htm)

Under Setup->Data.com Administration->Clean->Clean Rules

Select which rule you'd like to activate, and it will rather quickly populate the data.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to geocode all of your existing address information. ( beware of callout limits ).  Also you need to setup a trigger and call a service that will encode new/updated account information.

[Are latitude and longitude saved automatically?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/82453/are-latitude-and-longitude-saved-automatically/82462#82462)